# Is Lord Shiva both Creator and Destroyer?

Tags: shiva, parvati, universe, prakruti, iskcon

([From the lecture by HG Amogh Lila Prabhu](https://youtu.be/0n13r73pwP8))

1:29-1:58

HG says that “all beings enter the Brahmand through the union of Lord Shiva and Prakirti” (Mother Parvati?).

Is this true, can someone elaborate?
Please also provide explanations from Puranas.

Comment: SadaShiva has 5 functions (Pancha Kritya): 1) Shristi  (creation) 2) Sthiti (preservation) 3) Samhara (destruction) 4) Tirodhana (veiling) 5) Anugraha (grace)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he is both the creator and destroyer according to Shaivism. Brahma and Vishnu are equated to Rudra but Shiva is far above them all. I am quoting from the (Shaiva) Linga Purana:

> **He who is Rudra, Brahma and Visnu is called Siva** in the Puranas by virtue of his eternally and intrinsically enlightened and pure nature ([3.10](https://archive.org/details/LingaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart1/page/n13/mode/2up))

> Prakriti is the creator of worlds when she is presided over by Purusa (3.13)

With regard to your quotation here is a verse from the same place:

> In all these cosmic eggs there are four-faced Brahmas, Visnus and Rudras. They are all created by Pradhana after coming into contact with Siva ([3.34](https://archive.org/details/LingaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart1/page/n15/mode/2up))

So it says Prakriti is creator. But actually it is Shiva, because in the very first verse it says

> **The non-characterized is the root** of the characterized. The manifest Prakriti is the characterized, while **Siva is the non-characterized.** (3.1)

Lord Vishnu explained this:

> There is no other greater living being than him. He is a great mystery, the dimensional abode of intellect and the coveted goal of spiritualists. **He split himself into two. His un-qualitative part remained unmenifest; the qualitative one came into appearance. Of him who was aware of activities of Prakrti and who was inaccessible and fathomless, the seed was born**, formerly, at the first creation, riiis seed was laid into my womb which, after the lapse of some time, grew into a golden egg in the ocean. ([20.75-79](https://archive.org/details/LingaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart1/page/n79/mode/2up?view=theater))

Lord Brahma in the same Purana says this to Lord Shiva:

> O lord, this entire universe is born out of your body... **You protect and destroy everything.** ([31.41-42](https://archive.org/details/LingaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart1/page/n133/))

Comment: You’re the first person to answer a question that I asked.Now,you say “Prakirti is...Purusa”(3.13)Who is Purusa?Is Pradhana and Prakirti the same thing?

Comment: @Amethyst Yes Pradhana and Prakriti are the same (this is given in verse 2 of Chapter 3). Purusha is the male aspect which emerged after Shiva split himself into two. I will give the quotation for this as well in the answer :)

Comment: I believe that all this is from the Linga Puran.But there is one catch:HG says in this lecture that the Shiva Puran is true in declaring Lord Shiva’s supremacy,but mentions that Sukadeva Goswami saying that this is only for 1 out of 14 Manvantars,namely Tamas Manvantar,which itself happens by the permission and will of Lord Vishnu.In the rest 13,Lord Vishnu is Supreme.

Comment: Shiv is free from Gunas so that is impossible. **Vishnu is Taamsik** in nature according to Shiva & Skanda Puraans, while Rudra is Sattvik in nature. The great goddess Shivaa (Kali) is of all 3 natures. Vishnu came much after Shiva & Shakti and he is only equal to Rudra so that is impossible. **Actually even a mere sage easily defeated Vishnu.... and Rudra then burned Vishnu (Ling Puran 99.20-100.2)**

Comment: @R Kaushik so you mean to say the notion of “giving” supremacy in one manvantar goes to say that HG is misinformed?I mean,HG attributes this to Sukadeva Goswami,you can see the video timestamps.As for MahaVishnu being tamasik,even stotras of Lord Shiva like the Mahimna Stotram say that Lord Vishnu is sattvik.

Comment: Please read what I wrote again. Manvantar is very small compared to what I said. Coming to these Vaishnav people they are all reading Tamsik Purans of Vishnu so yes they are misinformed. Stotra by gandharva is not sacred scripture.... Even Shiv Puran says that Vishnu is sattvik.... but only in the view of activities in this world. Vishnu is actually Tamsik from the inside.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “manvantar is very small”.Please elaborate on “Even Shiv...the inside”.Also,what is your take on Padma Puran classifying some Puranas that hold Lord Shiv in high regard,as “tamasik “?

Comment: What is your opinion on the Bhagavad Gita?

Comment: 14 Manvantar = 1 Kalp = 1 day of Brahma. Shakti herself created Brahma, Vishnu and Rudra. Shakti was created by Shiv. So the Manvantar unit of time is too small and **Shiv is the original/eternal lord from the very beginning when there was not even Shakti...... let alone Vishnu or Brahma**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124996/discussion-between-amethyst-and-r-kaushik).